# Appclip is unavailable

Tags: apple-appclips

Last year, I released my app clip on the App Store.

While I can successfully launch the app clip through iMessage or by using the link URL, encountering **the same URL through scanning the QR code** results in an

> App clip is unavailable

Interestingly, during this scenario, I can still view my application name and banner accurately.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?